# Bundler & Minifier Extension Issue on Visual Studio 2017rc

Tags: visual-studio, azure, bundler, minify, visual-studio-2017

About one month ago I downloaded a brand new Visual studio 2017RC.
I created  a couple of projects. 
Everything working perfect.

Yesterday I published My project on Azure perfectly but my custom CSS not working at all.After hour of investigation I guess that there is Bundler & Minifier extension problem. I'm unable to install extension because there is no supported version for visual studio 2017RC

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the CSS is there in Azure? Just go to yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net if you are using Web Apps.

Comment: yes, I checked and there it is

Comment: Then, check F12 tools when you access the page, maybe it'll tell you more?